# PHP mail inside function with if/else statements

Tags: php

Trying to get my script to send me an email if the file uploads successfully. Here is my part of the script that saves the file to the server as username.site.zip:

```
 if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $_SESSION['myusername'] . '.site.' . $ext)){
        return array('success'=>true);}
    else {      
        return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
            'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
    }
```

I'm not quite sure how to add in the mail function so that if it's success=>true then it sends mail('email@domain.com','subject','body');

Any help would be great.

Comment: start here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php come back after extensive reading

Comment: I did try adding it, I am new to PHP so I was trying to add it after the success array and trying to base it off that instead of figuring to have it prior. Right in between the return array and previous if statement. Novice mistake, but it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $_SESSION['myusername'] . '.site.' . $ext)){
    $message = "The file was successfully uploaded.";
    mail('email@domain.com', 'My Subject', $message);
    return array('success'=>true);
} else {      
    return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
        'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
}
?>
```

You had it. Not sure what you still needed.

Comment: I had it set after the

    return array('success'=>true);

Not sure if that would stop the command.

Comment: Yes, after returning a value, PHP ends the execution of the rest of the function, at least according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php). Also, please mark the answer that helped you as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your mail command right before the return of the `success=>true` array like this:

```
if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $_SESSION['myusername'] . '.site.' . $ext)){

    mail('email@domain.com','subject','body');

    return array('success'=>true);}
else {      
    return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
        'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
}
```

Maybe encapsulate it in a try-catch block, but this should work right out of the box.